# "Twilight Zone" episode: young boy lures his​ female teacher home, his family is afraid of angering him because of his powers

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

I watched an episode of *The Twilight Zone* where a young boy lures his teacher home because he takes a liking to her. We then find out he's very powerful and his family live in fear of angering him.

Comment: "It's a Good Life" is the classic "family lives in fear of their child" story from The Twilight Zone. Are you sure that's not it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It's_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)

Comment: That's from the Twilight Zone movie, tho I don't remember the name of the particular segment.

Comment: It was first an episode. :) Well, first a short story, that got made into an episode, was remade for the movie, and then had a sequel in the reboot.

Comment: Possibly the most famous Twilight Zone episode of all time, or at least definitely in the Top Five. Personally, I think the only one that's more well-known is Shatner and his "Stewardess, there's some... thing... on the wing!"

Comment: @fffoolish, if the answer below is correct, don't forget to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 11):

<strike>Could it be ["It's a Good Life"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)) which aired in 1963. The plot summary doesn't mention a teacher, but it talks about Anthony Fremont, a 6 year old boy, who's town live in fear of him because of his power, which consist of "God-like mental powers" and mind control, and isolates his town from the outside?</strike>

---

It's actually the film [*Twilight Zone: The Movie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Zone:_The_Movie) which features a 1983 remake of the original episode [*"It's a Good Life"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)). The final third of the film directed by Joe Dante consists of a school teacher bumping into Anthony and driving him home, after breaking his bike.

Here's a quote from the [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086491/synopsis) page:

> The third segment is directed by Joe Dante and is a loose remake of the episode "It's a Good Life". Helen Foley (Kathleen Quinlan) is a mild-mannered school teacher who is travelling to her new job across the country. While visiting a rural bar/diner for directions from the owner Walter (Dick Miller), she witnesses a young boy (Jeremy Licht) playing a video game and then being accosted by a group of rowdy drunks for "accidentally" turning off the TV they were watching. Soon after, Helen decides to leave. Not paying attention, she backs into the boy with her car in the parking lot, damaging his bike. Helen offers the boy, Anthony, a ride home.
>
> They eventually get to Anthony's house, which is an immense home in the country. When Helen arrives, she meets some people whom Anthony tells her are his family, his Uncle Walt (Kevin McCarthy) and his sister Ethel (Nancy Cartwright). Also included in the family are Anthony's parents. Helen notices that the family seems extremely apprehensive, though she dismisses it. Anthony shows Helen around the house, including his sister's room; Anthony tells Helen that the girl is his "other" sister Sara (Cherie Currie), who got involved in an accident. The camera pans down and the audience view that the girl has no mouth, unbeknownst to Helen.

This is a clip from the start of the segment:

You can see [a segment at the house](https://vimeo.com/38320380) on Vimeo.

**NB:**
There was a sequel made during the 2002 [reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_(2002_TV_series)) called [*It's Still a Good Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Still_a_Good_Life) featuring Anthony as a middle-aged man, still terrorising his town, including banishing his wife and father a mythical *cornfield*. However his mother finds out that his daughter, Audrey, has inherited his powers

> And can bring people back from their banishment in the *cornfield*

<sub>Shoutout to @FuzzyBoots for finding the videos, and <sub><sub>deleting his answer.</sub></sub></sub>